# ffmpeg vaapi encoding with opencl filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to encode with `hevc_vaapi` and also to filter with `nlmeans_opencl`.

I've tried many combinations, such as

```
ffmpeg -y -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -init_hw_device vaapi=vaapi -init_hw_device opencl=opencl -filter_hw_device opencl -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i input.mp4 -vf "format=yuv420p,hwupload,hwmap=derive_device=opencl,nlmeans_opencl=4.0:7:5:5:5,hwmap=derive_device=vaapi:reverse=1:extra_hw_frames=16,format=vaapi" -c:v hevc_vaapi -rc_mode CQP -global_quality 25  output.mp4
```

the error is always

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_format_5' and the filter 'auto_scale_1'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
```

Is there a way to do that? If so, what is the minimum set of options to pass to ffmpeg? (I guess that some of the options above are wrong or unneded)

Thanks for any comment or suggestion.